# C++ union definition

Tags: c++, unions

Is is possible to define a union like we can do for named namespace ? I mean can we declare a first type in the union and then in another file add another type to the union ?

For now, I have a based class that contains a union of bit types (unsigned int and other which correspond to each derived class). I would like to split them in the derive class and construct bit by bit this union.

Comment: No, you can't split a union definition over multiple files.

Comment: @swan- I guess you have not grasped the logic for OOP. A class has a concept. Those that inherit that class just get a bit more specialised but have the same properties that it inherits.

Comment: I see there is a problem, but I can't see how to fix it. I need to know at the base class level what is in the union as a 4B unsigned int and in the lower classes I need the more precise definition in bits. I use union because the conversion from unsigned int to bit structure is very convenient

Comment: @slugonamission - not even in the same file.

Answer (score 4):

No, such as for `structs/classes`, `enums`.

n3337 7.3/1

> A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region. The name of a namespace can be used to access
> entities declared in that namespace; that is, the members of the namespace.***Unlike other declarative regions***,
> **the definition of a namespace can be split over several parts of one or more translation units.**

Answer (score 1):

No.  How could it even be made to work (not that it's desirable), with
separate compilation.  Consider something like:

```
union U { int i; double d; }

void
f()
{
    U aU;
    g( &aU );
    //  ...
}
```

How much space is the compiler to allocated on the stack for `aU`.
Given that a DLL not yet written contains:

```
union U { char buff[1000]; };

void
g( U* aU )
{
    //  Use all 1000 bytes...
}
```

(Note that according to the standard, the above is undefined behavior.
What you are asking would require it to work.)

Comment: That is because I would add smaller type than the 4B unsigned int.